# What exactly is the code for accessing AppDelegate doing?

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I'm curious what exactly the line of code below does and why this specific syntax is used to reference the AppDelegate.

```
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).method_or_variable_name
```

Also, how is this syntax different from these ones?

```
AppDelegate().whatever_method_that_is_in_AppDelegate
AppDelegate.whatever_variable_of_App_Delegate
```

As I was developing using Swift, I figured out that whenever accessing a variable of a script I should use the StructName.variable syntax whereas whenever accessing a method of a script, I should use the StructName().method syntax. I'm still a beginner in Swift, so I have a strong feeling I am not using "Swifty" practices.

I would appreciate some insight.

Comment: are you familiar with "static" members of classes ?

Comment: I think you should read up on UIApplication and UIApplicationDelegate to understand the first line of code. The second one is just plain wrong and you will know that when you understand the first line. The third one is ok _if_ you static variables in your AppDelegate class

Comment: @Fattie Yes, but I am having trouble understanding (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).method_or_variable_name. I'm confused specifically about how UIApplication.shared.delegate can be used to access AppDelegate when they share different names and definitions. Is it a special syntax in Swift?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson So is UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate the syntax for accessing an existing instance of the AppDelegate class, whereas AppDelegate().method creates a new instance of the object to access its methods?

Comment: You should always use the first option since the OS is using that instance to communicate with your app. A new instance will not be known by the OS and therefore useless.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you for providing me insight. Just to be sure, (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate) this kind of syntax can only be used to access native classes already defined in Apple Developer Documentation, right? If I had to access a method of a class I created, I would have to create an instance?

Comment: Yes that is correct. But the way the app delegate object is accessed is a special case in itself and not the usual way you interact with classes from the UIKit or other Apple frameworks

Comment: Two notions: instance vs class methods or var, that's one point. The second one, I'd say, it's new instance vs singletong pattern. These knowledges are important to know in general in Object Oriented Programming, not only Swift.